# In Shopify how do I set the sort order of comments by most recent first?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I make it so that the most recent comment display first? I haven't been able to find this in the documentation and currently my comments are out of order.

This is in my article template:

```
{% for comment in article.comments %}
<li id="{{ comment.id }}" class="comment{% unless number_of_comments > article.comments_count %}{% if forloop.first %} first{% endif %}{% endunless %}{% if forloop.last %} last {% endif %}">
{% include 'comment' %}
</li>
{% unless forloop.last %}
```

and in my comments include:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter">
    <span class="comment-author">{{ comment.author }}</span>
    <span class="comment-date">
      {{ comment.created_at | time_tag: format: 'month_day_year' }}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item medium-up--three-quarters">
    <div class="rte">
      {% comment %}ly_code_replace_for_[ comment.content ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% include 'ly-content' with comment %}{{ ly_translation }}{% comment %}ly_code_replace_end{% endcomment %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: In order to resolve this I had to add:

```
{% assign artComments = article.comments | sort: "created_at" | reverse %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`reversed` parameter](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#reversed) in your for loop tag:

```
{% for comment in article.comments reversed %}
  ... do your thing
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need them in reverse, I need them sorted by date.  Right now they are completely loading in random order.

Comment: I very much doubt they are random. According to Shopify's API docs; "A comment is a reader's response to an article in a blog. Comments appear on the article page in reverse chronological order" — https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/comment

Comment: That is true, but not if you are importing them using a bulk uploader.

Comment: A bulk uploading app? Sounds like that is the issue